# Error 1001 OnAfterInstall --> Cannot Find File Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service, windows-services

How do I fix this error?

[image]

Service installs but does not start.

I attempted to run this troubleshooter to fix the install, but it didnt work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

I also tried rebooting and trying the installer again, which did not work again

Comment: It is because [the service changes directory to System32](https://serverfault.com/questions/114238/windows-service-can-i-configure-the-current-working-directory#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Windows%20services%20start,C%3A%5CWINDOWS%5Csystem32%20). and that is not where your code will be looking for whatever it is looking for.

Comment: So do you know how I would change the working directory? Would it be in ProjectInstaller or in custom actions?

Comment: The link I provided has a number of options.